# How to get a Google OAuth 2 token for api testing

Tags: api, oauth, httprequest, postman, google-oauth

I am trying to build a simple node API that uses google OAuth 2.0 to authenticate endpoints, and I am trying to test it by making calls with Postman, but I cannot figure out how to get an OAuth token for my google account to use when calling the API. I tried using the OAuth feature in Postman but could not get it configured properly. Can anyone give me any guidance on how to either obtain a token I can use or properly use Postman/any other utility to do this testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can use [Google's Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button) template to initialize the login & grant of permissions process (provided the project is set up in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)):

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="{{ OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID }}">

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="google-signin-button"
     class="g-signin2"
     data-width="170"
     data-height="30"
     data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
     data-onfailure="onSignInFailure">
</div>
```

```js
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;//this is your token
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @EvanSnapp - If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for to set the `Bearer` for the `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` API. Just I've needed the `access_token` instead of the `id_token`